# PreferenceActivity, how to make a Preference item that will navigate back through menus?

Tags: java, android, preferenceactivity

My overriding question is this:  In Android `PreferenceActivity`, how can I write an `OnClickListener` which will have the same functionality as pressing the Android back button as I navigate through `PreferenceScreen` defined menus?  That is to say, I would like users of my App to explicity see a menu choice "Back" which will bring them to the previous menu, or bring them out of the menu activity to their previous activity if they are at the root of this particular `PreferenceActivity` session.

The [android developer documents tell us](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html)

> Note that this XML resource contains a preference screen holding another fragment, the Prefs1FragmentInner implemented here. This allows the user to traverse down a hierarchy of preferences; pressing back will pop each fragment off the stack to return to the previous preferences.

And they are correct about that.  I navigate happily through my menus by clicking on `PreferenceScreen` items to get to that screen, and using the Android back button to go Back up a level.  But I'm not sure a casual user really understands the "Back" button, I know I didn't until I read about it in Developer docs.  SO I would would like them to have an explicit `Preference` defined menu choice whos `OnClickListener` duplicates the function of the Android back button.

So I tried to put in a Preference in my menu that would go back.  Having determined that a not Overriden `onBackPressed` in a my subclass of `PreferenceActivity` just referred back to `Activity.onBackPressed()` which merely calls `finish()`, I tried this `OnClickListener`:

```java
private OnPreferenceClickListener clickFinishesSuccessfully = new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
};
```

As it turns out, this did NOT do the same thing as pressing the back button!  Pressing this button always took me out of the `PreferenceActivity` entirely, back to the `Activity` from which I had called my `PreferenceActivity`.  Specifically, it did NOT navigate back through my menus no matter how deep I was when I clicked it.

I am guessing here: When I have gotten to a submenu by clicking an onscreen preference which is really a `PreferenceScreen`, I am no longer in my own `PreferenceActivity`.  I must be in some other Activity?

So my functional question: what can I put in my OnClickListener of my "Back" `Preference` to get the same function as the Android Back button navigating through my menus?

Answer (score 0):

I think the casual user should know about the back button. The button is used everywhere so it might be a problem getting used in the first day but after that it's natural. Without being used to the "back" button I can hardly imagine doing the everyday tasks.

The preference you want to add just duplicates functionality and doesn't provide a consistent way with the rest of the system. If Google was considering back being an uncommon thing for casual users would have added that option in phone's Settings which is also a PreferenceActivity.

Comment: Problem is not in user experience with BACK button. I have the same problem - when user click my preference - I do some work and want to go one level up in my preferences. For example when user click 'logof' I have to move him one level up to hide some preferences.